# How can I locate definition of function in R?

Tags: r, introspection

In rStudio, I can `go to definition`.

But In R console how can I find location with code?

```
> show_somewhat_location_of_function(dplyr::src_dbi)
```

I see that I can view source code in REPL. But How can I get Location of function?

```
file: some_x.R
line: 42
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `src_dbi` is a function from `dbplyr` and not `dplyr`.

To get the definition of that function (or the code of that function), just type the function with the brackets so they're not treated as a function call:

```
dbplyr::src_dbi
```

And R output:

```
function (con, auto_disconnect = FALSE) 
{
    if (is_false(auto_disconnect)) {
        disco <- NULL
    }
    else {
        disco <- db_disconnector(con, quiet = is_true(auto_disconnect))
    }
    structure(list(con = con, disco = disco), class = c("src_dbi", 
        "src_sql", "src"))
}
<environment: namespace:dbplyr>
```

Which tells me the namespace and the definition of that function.